# I am trying to make a function that adds 1 to either opps_score or bets_score but when I print the results the default value is printed

Tags: java

```
int bets_score = 0;
int opps_score=0;
```

When I call this method it shoud return `1` to either `bets_score` or `opps_score`

```
    b.getCSRecordOdds(wins, loses, opps_wins, opps_loses, bets_score, opps_score);

      if (bets_score > opps_score) {
        System.out.println("You're bet is looking good \n 
                            Score: " + bets_score+" to " + opps_score);
    } else {
        System.out.println("You should probably sit this one out \n 
                            Score: " + opps_score+" to " + bets_score);
    }
```

This is the abstract method

```
public int getCSRecordOdds(int cs_bets_wins, int cs_bets_loses, int cs_opps_wins, int cs_opps_loses, int bets_score, int opps_score){
    if (cs_bets_wins / cs_bets_loses > cs_opps_wins / cs_opps_loses) {
       bets_score = bets_score +1;
       return bets_score;        
    } else {
       opps_score = opps_score +1;
       return opps_score;     
    }
}
```

Comment: You will probably need to instantiate `double`s or `float`s because dividing an int/int will try to create an int, which is not always the case. You are also not handling a div/0 error

Comment: `bets_score, opps_score` are passed by value. Also, you ignore the return value.

Comment: Make the scores static and reference the class containing them directly `yourClass.bets_score = yourClass.bets_score +1;`, or you need to get the return value `int result = b.getCSRecordOdds(...);` then `System.out.println("Result: '+result);`